# How does completeness axiom provide the existence of irrational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

So I've been reflecting on the Completeness Axiom. It is said that this is what provides continuity to the real numbers. An example is the set $S = {x: x^2 <2}$. This will have no least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$, but will in $\Bbb R$. Now if it is to be said that it is the Completeness Axiom that provides this continuity, that has to mean that he existence of $\sqrt 2$ is provided axiomatically by the completeness axiom. If $\sqrt 2$ is to exist based on some other reason/principle/axiom, then that will be what provides continuity, and the completeness axiom will just be a restatement of something it has no part in creating, and thus won't even be an axiom anymore.

I am on this philosophical query because it seems from everywhere I read that it is in fact the completeness axiom that provides continuity. Then it must be that the existence of $\sqrt 2$ is provided axiomatically by the completeness axiom. Am I correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuity"?

Comment: What continuity is is part of what I'm trying to figure out. From what I've read so far the completeness axiom implies there are no gaps or missing points in the real line, and the stated example is often used to illustrate this. So I'm using "continuity" as an expression for this concept but please tell me if I've been inaccurate in that regard.

Comment: You're right - the completeness axiom asserts that your set $S$ has a least upper bound $b$, and from this description and other axioms we can deduce that $b^2=2$, so we call this element $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Depending on how you construct the real numbers, completeness may be assumed (thus, an axiom) or be proved from the construction itself. So your question is kinda weirdly worded. Assuming for the sake of argument that it is taken as an axiom, then, since it is equivalent to the least upper bound property, one can prove that the LUB property plus the fact that the real numbers are a field (and some additional assumptions on the order relation) imply that for all $x < y$ there is $z$ such that $x < z < y$. So the real numbers are called by topologists a "linear continuum".

Comment: "If $\sqrt 2$ is to exist based on some other reason/principle/axiom, then that will be what provides completeness" - not necessarily, since completeness is much stronger than the existence of $\sqrt 2$: There are fields that include $\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2$ that are much smaller than $\Bbb R$ and not complete.

Comment: Sorry to shift a bit to philosophy... What means that $\sqrt 2$ exists??? However a fascinating question!

Comment: There is an ordered field $F$ with $\mathbb Q \subsetneq F \subsetneq \mathbb R$ where $\sqrt2 \in F$ but completeness fails somewhere else.

Comment: "If 2–√ is to exist based on some other reason/principle/axiom, then that will be what provides continuity" Not necessarily.  $\sqrt 2$ is just one number and it alone can not account for "filling in" the uncountable "discontinuities".  Even if you had an axiom to provide the existence of all numbers, it may not provide for the order or that they they *be* "continuous".

Comment: To go back to you question *how* does completeness axiom provide existence of irrational numbers.... well, it's just as you said.  If our universe had not irrational numbers then we'd only have rationals. The set $S= \{q\in \mathbb Q|q^2 < 2\}$ is bounded above but has no least upper bound violating the completeness axiom. So the least upper bound of $S$ (which must exist because of the Comp. Axiom) can not be rational.  So there must be numbers that are not rational.

Comment: Asking about "alternative axioms" are inavoidably vague.  Suppose we had the rationals and rather than the completeness axiom, I had a Square Root Axiom:  For every $a$ in our system there will exist at least one $x$ in our system so that $x^2 = a$. Then we'd have irrationals.  $\sqrt{2}$ can not be rational and neither can $\sqrt{-5}$.  But we don't have continuity.  Cube roots do not exist and $W=\{q|q^3 < 2\}$ is bounded above but does not have a least upper bound. Nor does $P=\{q$ so that $q\times$ the diameter of the circle is less than the cirumference of the circle$\}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think the poster has the mathematical pre-requisites to understand the answer.

Comment: Or I could have just a Square root of two axiom.  Axiom.  There exists a number so that $x^2 =2$.  That's the entirity of the axiom.......

Comment: The existence of the square root of two has nothing to do with completeness. Cut two unit squares at the diagonals and glue them together to form a new square. What is that square's area? So, by definition, how long are its sides?

Comment: @JohnDouma That assumes an axiom of all possible geometric lengths coresponding to numbers.  Such an axiom implies "continuity" as geometry as an axiom of being continuous. Which is kind of why we *want* a completeness axiom in the first place.  It's not that the CA assures irrational directly.  It's that rationals only leaves numbers incomplete so irrationals are required.... if we want completeness and geometric continuity.

Comment: @fleablood That assumes nothing. That demonstrates that the square root of two exists, whether it is rational or not. That was what Pythagoras was facing. He know the diagonal of a square had a length that could not be expressed as the ratio of two numbers.

Comment: But we have to formulate what it means for geometric shapes to have "lengths".  That's *why* we made any of these axioms and why we *have* the axiom of completeness.  Because however we construct numbers we want geometric lengths to be numbers and vice versa.  That in essence is what the axiom of completeness is.  Just formal.

Comment: After reading the answers it seems clear that there is quite a lot more to this concept than I thought, and completeness and continuity will not be understood simply by interpreting the Completeness Axiom.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect (you have to tell!) that what you mean by continuity is the fact that the real line has the [linear continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum) property, namely that:

1. It has the least upper bound property
2. and for each $x,y$ satisfying $x \lt y$, there exists $z$ such that $x \lt z \lt y$.

From there, I suggest that you have a look at the various way to [build the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers). This is instructive of the way the completeness of $\mathbb R$ is deduced.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things I could say here. I’m going to ramble a bit, and hopefully some proper subset of the things I say will answer your questions.

First, I think we should be careful to separate the *order properties* of $\mathbb{R}$ from the *algebraic properties* of $\mathbb{R}$. The existence of irrational numbers is an algebraic property of $\mathbb{R}$, while completeness is an order property.

Let’s first examine some properties of linear orders.

**Density:** an order $(L, \leq)$ is dense if and only if for every pair of points $x,y \in L$ with $x \leq y$, there is a third point $z \in L$ such that $x \leq z \leq y$. We can think of this as “if you give me any two points, we can find a point in between them”.

**Completeness:** an order $(L, \leq)$ is complete if and only if every bounded subset $A \subseteq L$ has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound.

In some sense, both of these correspond to the order feeling “continuous”. I would caution against thinking of completeness as “continuity”. Perhaps an example will illustrate why.

We may take obvious order-preserving injections $\mathbb{Q} \: \hookrightarrow \: \mathbb{R} \: \hookrightarrow \:^*\mathbb{R}$. If you’re unfamiliar, $^*\mathbb{R}$ denotes the “hyperreal numbers”. The hyperreals are an ordered field which is non-Archimedean. In particular, there are “infinite” and “infinitesimal” hyperreal numbers.

All three orders $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $^* \mathbb{R}$ are dense, but only $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. When we extend to the hyperreals, we add an infinitesimal $\epsilon$ such that for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $0 < \epsilon < r$. This sure “feels” like plugging a hole in the real numbers, doesn’t it? But the real numbers were complete. So what hole could we be plugging if the real numbers have no holes to plug? This is why I would advocate for thinking of completeness in a different way than continuity.

If you want an interpretation of completeness that makes sense, we might pass to the world of topology. I don’t know if you’ve learned any topology yet, but if you give me an ordered set $(L, \leq)$, we may put a topology on $L$ generated from half-open intervals. One may show the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $(L, \leq)$ be endowed with the order topology. $L$ is connected if and only if the order is dense and complete.

This “connected” notion might be more useful than “continuity”.

Bringing this back to the world of algebra, it is a minor miracle to me that taking the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ to get $\mathbb{R}$ preserves the field properties of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is not always the case. There are ordered fields that cannot be completed to get another field. The alignment of “irrational numbers” and “Dedekind cuts” is a consequence of this miracle.